# INSERT INTO Table1(dat) VALUES(20/7);

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO Table1(dat) VALUES(20/7);
```

The above question/subject, returns `2.857` in the field when I run the SQL command. The field data type is `varchar(5)`. I also used `char(5)` but that also did not work!

However, I don't want it to perform any calculation while inserting the value into the table1.
I want it to insert the text `'20/7'` as it is inputted.
Can you describe what to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Use single quotes for strings:**

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (dat) VALUES('20/7');
```

Comment: Thanks , Your answer gave me the right solution. I don't know why I forgot to use the '   '. Kudos.